# Finding duplicates in sorted, linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, duplicates, sortedlist

I've created a sorted linked list and now I'm trying to figure out how to remove duplicates. I wanted to add code that would do this in the Add method I created but I can't seem to figure it out. I feel like this should be relatively easy but I'm a bit brain dead right now.

In my add method I check the index to see where an item is to be added. "Index" is an int variable but I wanted to check to see if "item", a comparable, was the same item stored before it.  I wanted to use the compareTo method but I would get a type mismatch. Does anyone have an idea of a better way to do this?

Here is the code for my add method:

```
 package sortedListReferenceBased;

     public class SortedListReferenceBasedIterativeNoDuplicates
     implements SortedListInterface {

     // reference to linked list of items
     private Node head; 
     private int numItems; // number of items in list

     public SortedListReferenceBasedIterativeNoDuplicates() {
     numItems = 0;
     head = null;
     }  // end default constructor

      public boolean sortedIsEmpty() {
        return numItems == 0;
      //TODO
     }  // end sortedIsEmpty

     public int sortedSize() {
  return numItems;
      //TODO
     }  // end sortedSize

      private Node find(int index) {
     // --------------------------------------------------
     // Locates a specified node in a linked list.
     // Precondition: index is the number of the desired
    // node. Assumes that 1 <= index <= numItems+1
    // Postcondition: Returns a reference to the desired 
   // node.
  // --------------------------------------------------
  Node curr = head;
  for (int skip = 1; skip < index; skip++) {
   curr = curr.getNext();
} // end for
return curr;
  } // end find


  public Comparable sortedGet(int index) 
                throws ListIndexOutOfBoundsException {
      if (index >= 1 && index <= numItems){
          Node curr = find(index);
          Object dataItem = curr.getItem();
          return (Comparable) dataItem;
      }
      else {
          throw new ListIndexOutOfBoundsException("List index out of bounds on   get.");
  }
    //TODO
  } // end sortedGet()


  public void sortedAdd(Comparable item) throws ListException{ 
   int index = locateIndex(item); //to find location where item should be added
   if( index >=1 && index <= numItems+1){
       //if adding an item to the very beginning of list
       if (index == 1){
           Node newNode = new Node(item,head);
           head = newNode;
       }
       if (item.compareTo(something something?)== 0){ //if item is a duplicate of previous item do nothing
           System.out.println("No duplicates!");
       }

       //advances 
       else {
           Node prev = find(index-1); //finds out where previous node is
           Node newNode = new Node(item, prev.getNext()); //creates Node with item you wish to add
           prev.setNext(newNode); //links new node with previous node
          }
          numItems++;  
      }//end main if statement
      else {
           throw new ListIndexOutOfBoundsException("List index out of bounds on add.");
      }
    //TODO
  }  // end sortedAdd()


  public void sortedRemove(Comparable item) throws ListException {
      int index = locateIndex(item);
      if (index >= 1 && index <= numItems){ //if the index is greater than 1 (meaning list not empty) and
                                              //index doesn't exceed list size do the following:
      //if index is value of one then delete first node in this special way
      if (index == 1) {
          head = head.getNext();
      }
    //if there is only one item in the list then set head to nothing so index out of bounds error won't occur
      if (numItems == 1){
          head = null;
      }
      else { //if none of these things occur go ahead and delete item, allocating Nodes accordingly
          Node prev = find(index-1);
          Node curr = prev.getNext();
          prev.setNext(curr.getNext());
      }
      numItems--;//must account for one less item
      }
  if (!sortedIsEmpty()){
      System.out.println("Item does not exist!");
  }
  else { //if index doesn't meet if statement requirements 
      throw new ListIndexOutOfBoundsException("List index out of bounds on remove.");
  }

//TODO
 } // end sortedRemove


 public void sortedRemoveAll() {
   // setting head to null causes list to be
   // unreachable and thus marked for garbage 
   // collection
   head = null;
   numItems = 0;
 } // end sortedRemoveAll


 //Returns the position where item belongs or exists in a sorted list;
 //item and the list are unchanged.
 public int locateIndex(Comparable item) {
     Node curr = head;
     for (int i = 1; i <= sortedSize(); i++){
         if (item.compareTo(curr.getItem())<= 0){
            return i;
        }//end if

         else {
             curr = curr.getNext();
         }//end else
     }//end for
     return sortedSize()+1; 
    //TODO
 } //end locateIndex()




} // end ListReferenceBased
```

I apologize for the strange formatting. It's pretty rough right now. I also apologize if this question is really obvious! Haha

Answer (score 4):

Preliminary points:

1. I don't understand why you appear to be trying to implement linked lists in Java ... given that there is already a perfectly good implementation in the form of `java.util.LinkedList`.
2. A collection with no duplicates is a set ...
3. A set based on linked lists is going to be suboptimal.  For instance, insertion is `O(N)` compared with `O(logN)` for tree-based implementation, and `O(1)` for a hashtable based implementation (assuming it is sized appropriately).  `java.util.TreeSet` and `java.util.HashSet` are examples respectively.

Having said that, and assuming that you actually want an insight / hint ...

If you have a presorted linked-list, then the way to remove duplicates is to step through the nodes, comparing `node.value` with `node.next.value`.  If the values are equal, then you've found a duplicate, and you can remove it by changing `node.next` to `node.next.next`.  Your code will also need to cope with various "edge cases"; e.g. lists with 0 or 1 element, etc.

Comment: It's an assignment for my Data Structures class. My teacher asked us to create it in this manner. We haven't learned about trees. hashtables, or anything like that yet so we're trying to do this assignment with very little knowledge. Hence why it's so strange.  Thank you for your insight!

Answer (score 0):

Are you set on using a linked list?  Using the built-in [TreeSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) would seem to be a much more natural fit for this.

Comment: I'll look in to it for future reference! Right now my assignment doesn't call for it. But thank you very much!

Comment: @Bell - makes more sense now that we know it's an assignment.  Whole point could be for you to see why linked lists aren't a good choice for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (locateIndex(item) != (sortedSize() + 1)) { //locateIndex returns sortedSize() + 1 if it didn't find the item, so we check that

    System.out.println("No duplicates!");
}
```

It's all about using code you have already written.